# Getting “undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here I have 3 models 
1.category
2.post
3.user

the post belongs_to category 
and the post belongs_to user as well, while I tried to render a new post view, it says "undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass"

Here is the code

routes.rb

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

MODELS

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
```

models/users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
```

models/categories.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end
```

CONTROLLERS

controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_category
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
    @posts = category.post
end

def show
  @post = category.posts.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:tittle, :content, :map, :bootsy_image_gallery_id, {postmages: []})
    end

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_category
        @category = Category.find(params[:post_id])
    end
  end
end
```

I need have a create post link in Category show page but the result never right.

VIEW

views/posts/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% if @post && @post.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</p>
      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure what cause the problem "undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass" while I tried to make a new post

Comment: Is that correct: `{postmages: []}`? I'd also like to see the full error message.